# How to bind variable using DCG in prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

[image]
[image]

Based on the code in the pics, How can I bind those unbounded variables with processing the structure? For example, how can I let the X=1,Y=2 for the example in first pic.

a more clear example:

I asked another question to be more specific. if it is still unclear,whatever.

[how to do Arithmetic Operations in DCG in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226727/how-to-do-arithmetic-operations-in-dcg-in-prolog)

Comment: Just add `, X=1, Y=2` to the line?

Comment: no,no,no,during the runtime, not assign after runtime

Comment: Then you put them before... :) `X=1, Y=2, ....` If that still doesn't meet your needs, then it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I edited question , how about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still unclear. You don't bind anything "manually", do you?

Do you mean that you do the unification in the head of the predicate?

```
foobar(1, 2) --> [1, 2].
```

(A trivial example, since I don't know if this is what you are asking.)