# how to do Arithmetic Operations in DCG in prolog

Tags: prolog, operators, dcg, clpfd

```
verb_phrase(X,P)--> trans_verb(X,X+1,P1), noun_phrase(X+1,P1,P).
```

For the code above, if X=1, I will get

```
(...1+1...).
```

"..."means not important code. 
but I really want to get 2 instead of 1+1.
Could someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reasoning over integers, the cleanest way is to use CLP(FD) constraints for arithmetic.

You can use `{}/1` within DCGs to embed Prolog goals. For example:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

verb_phrase(X0, P)--> { X #= X0 + 1 }, trans_verb(X0, X, P1), noun_phrase(X, P1, P).
```

Comment: Isn't there a `X #> 0` missing?